# Printer suddenly starts and prints message from libwww-perl

Tags: perl, httprequest, malware

We have a network printer that will suddenly fire up and print five lines (three times this month)

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate, gzip;q=0.03
Connection: TE, close
Host : <printer IP>:9100
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.13
```

I'm guessing that something is scanning ports, but don't know where it's coming from  - it only identifies the printer IP address. The network is all cable, no Wi-Fi enabled...

Any idea what could be doing this, and how it can it be located?

The printer is an old (probably 15 years at least) HP Colour LaserJet 4500N with it's own network card and will reply to a ping request from anywhere on the internet...

Thanks

Comment: I am thinking more like someone is trying to access a printer management web console and the printer does not support it or flipped into the wrong mode. Does the printer have some kind of management support through a web interface? Are there others in the company that do? If so, who is the manager?

Comment: Nothing to get paranoid about then? I changed the IP about eight years ago and I have no idea how I did it - the last management console I remember was with NetWare!!! - I doubt it supports web management.

Comment: Don't take my thought as a expert opinion. Something I would try is fire up a web browser and enter  http://<printer IP>:9100  See if it does something similar.

Comment: I would appear that that it is possible to connect via a browser - typing the IP into Edge or IE11 produces the HP icon and a help button (the help does work but the other buttons that should be there are clearly not supported any longer with modern browsers)

Comment: The user agent line does suggest there is some automated crawler visiting your printer.  https://github.com/libwww-perl/libwww-perl

Comment: Adding the port to the url does fire it up! It would also appear that 9100 is the standard port for printers. It takes about six years to warm up and print anything so waiting for the result

Comment: This time it recognised the user agent as Mozilla/5.0 Windows NT 10.0, so you are bang on the money. If you want to put that as the answer I can mark it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like some automated Perl script is trying to access the printer's web console. The User-Agent line tells the request comes from [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP), the most commonly used library to make web requests from Perl.

As you just found out, similar behavior can be invoked by just entering `http://<printerIP>:9100` in a web browser. Now it is only a matter of tracking down the visitor. You may find a log in the management console that gives you the visitor's IP address.